# Strange Golang SQL Error - WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, sqlx

I am running a query in Golang, using the sqlx library:

```
rows, dbErr := db.Queryx(`
    SELECT *
    FROM table_a as a
       INNER JOIN table_b AS b
          ON a.b_id = b.id
       WHERE b.id = 'b3c06feb-8bd1-42e1-b516-c1121990ff81';
    `)
```

The query is syntactically correct, and runs fine in Postico, terminal, etc. However when I try to run this query in Golang I get the error `pq: syntax error at or near "  WHERE"`

Can anyone explain this strange behaviour?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I thought you had to parentheses the clause of `ON` if you follow it with conditions of the parent `SELECT`.  As in, `ON (a.b_id = b.id)`.

Comment: @Kaedys hmm good suggestion, but I still get the same error

Comment: If postgres is reporting an error, it should show up in the postgres error log, along with the complete query -- can you check and verify that the query in the log matches what you're sending?

Comment: @jmelesky Yes that's a good point, but I'm not quite sure how to check that with our system. For certain the queries don't match up because there's no syntax error in the raw string. I'm currently looking into what sqlx is doing, will update when I have an answer.

Comment: @BlakeBrown did you try removing all the unnecessary whitespace and execute the query?

Comment: Second what @mkopriva said - I'm wondering if this could be a EOL issue. What are the line endings in your source file?

Comment: Dit you try it without the unnecessary semicolon?

Comment: Semicolon didn't make a difference

Answer (score 1):

The issue was outdated dependencies. We had to update our Golang sql libraries.

Thank you to everyone who submitted suggestions.